# Magento reports and timezone issues

Tags: magento-1.8, reports, timezone

When viewing the Total Ordered Report I'm getting the following error message

> This report depends on timezone configuration. Once timezone is changed, the lifetime statistics need to be refreshed.

I have my `/app/etc/config` and it has the following

```
<general>
<locale>
    <code>en_GB</code>
    <timezone>Europe/London</timezone>
</locale>
```

This matches what is set in the admin system under **System->Configuration->General->Locale options**.

I have tried to refresh the lifetime stats but this message still appears.

Please could someone advise

Answer (score 2):

This is a normal message that is always added to the page with reports.

If it irritates you, you can remove it from the layout (`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/sales.xml` and `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/report.xml`).

It will be no any problems for you if you have set up timezone and doesn’t change it. If your repots don’t work, it is another problem. Exactly can say that before viewing reports, you should update the statistics if it is outdated

Answer (score 0):

The timezone is not set in PHP. Add this to your php.ini - there may be more than one **php.ini** depending on your server/cli setup, so add this to all of them:

**date.timezone = "Europe/London"**

Now restart your web server.

Comment: Doing a phpinfo I can see the timezone is already set to `Default timezone  Europe/London `

Comment: Maybe it is how they get refreshed in Magento, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158854/reports-do-not-work-because-of-timezone-on-magento Also has you a cron job to update the reports automatically?